# How to handle malloc failing and returning NULL?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc, out-of-memory

I'm a bit confused on how to check if a memory allocation failed in order to prevent any undefined behaviours caused by a dereferenced `NULL` pointer. 
I know that `malloc` (and similiar functions) can fail and return `NULL`, and that for this reason the address returned should always be checked before proceeding with the rest of the program. What I don't get is what's the best way to handle these kind of cases. In other words: what is a program supposed to do when a `malloc` call returns `NULL`?

I was working on this implementation of a doubly linked list when this doubt raised.

```
struct ListNode {

    struct ListNode* previous;
    struct ListNode* next;
    void* object;
};

struct ListNode* newListNode(void* object) {

    struct ListNode* self = malloc(sizeof(*self));

    if(self != NULL) {

        self->next = NULL;
        self->previous = NULL;
        self->object = object;
    }

    return self;
}
```

The initialization of a node happens only if its pointer was correctly allocated. If this didn't happen, this constructor function returns `NULL`.

I've also written a function that creates a new node (calling the `newListNode` function) starting from an already existing node and then returns it.

```
struct ListNode* createNextNode(struct ListNode* self, void* object) {

    struct ListNode* newNext = newListNode(object);

    if(newNext != NULL) {

        newNext->previous = self;

        struct ListNode* oldNext = self->next;

        self->next = newNext;

        if(oldNext != NULL) {

            newNext->next = oldNext;
            oldNext->previous = self->next;
        }
    }

    return newNext;
}
```

If `newListNode` returns `NULL`, `createNextNode` as well returns `NULL` and the node passed to the function doesn't get touched.

Then the ListNode struct is used to implement the actual linked list.

```
struct LinkedList {

    struct ListNode* first;
    struct ListNode* last;
    unsigned int length;
};

_Bool addToLinkedList(struct LinkedList* self, void* object) {

    struct ListNode* newNode;

    if(self->length == 0) {

        newNode = newListNode(object);
        self->first = newNode;
    }
    else {

        newNode = createNextNode(self->last, object);
    }

    if(newNode != NULL) {

        self->last = newNode;
        self->length++;
    }

    return newNode != NULL;
}
```

if the creation of a new node fails, the `addToLinkedList` function returns 0 and the linked list itself is left untouched.

Finally, let's consider this last function which adds all the elements of a linked list to another linked list.

```
void addAllToLinkedList(struct LinkedList* self, const struct LinkedList* other) {

    struct ListNode* node = other->first;

    while(node != NULL) {

        addToLinkedList(self, node->object);
        node = node->next;
    }
}
```

How should I handle the possibility that `addToLinkedList` might return 0? For what I've gathered, `malloc` fails when its no longer possible to allocate memory, so I assume that subsequent calls after an allocation failure would fail as well, am I right? So, if 0 is returned, should the loop immediately stop since it won't be possible to add any new elements to the list anyway? 
Also, is it correct to stack all of these checks one over another the way I did it? Isn't it redundant? Would it be wrong to just immediately terminate the program as soon as malloc fails? I read that it would be problematic for multi-threaded programs and also that in some istances a program might be able to continue to run without any further allocation of memory, so it would be wrong to treat this as a fatal error in any possible case. Is this right?

Sorry for the really long post and thank you for your help!

Comment: There's not really a general answer - it depends on the larger context of the program.  Is there other useful work your program, as a whole, can do, without allocating this memory?  If yes, do it.  If not, exit.

Comment: It also depends somewhat on the platform. If `malloc` returns `NULL` on a platform such as Windows or Linux, then most likely something has gone seriously wrong in your program and it is almost always a fatal error.

Comment: @Jabberwocky It could also just be that there isn't enough available memory for the allocation. Sometimes there are artificial restrictions on memory too.

Comment: Once `malloc` has returned `NULL` do subsequent calls also return `NULL`?. Well this depends. The answer is most of the time "yes". It's very hard to give a general answer.

Comment: @GovindParmar yes, of course, there are many possible scenarios.

Comment: Actually you should consider available memory a bit like the gas in your car. You never want to run out of it. You always need some reserves, and when you run out of it you're most of the time out of luck

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What if malloc fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788803/what-if-malloc-fails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to handle malloc failing and returning NULL?

Consider if the code is a set of helper functions/library or application.

The decision to terminate is best handled by higher level code.

Example: Aside from `exit()`, `abort()` and friends, the Standard C library does not exit.

Likewise returning error codes/values is a reasonable solution for OP's low-level function sets too.  Even for `addAllToLinkedList()`, I'd consider propagating the error in the return code.  (Non-zero is some error.)

```
// void addAllToLinkedList(struct LinkedList* self, const struct LinkedList* other) {
int addAllToLinkedList(struct LinkedList* self, const struct LinkedList* other) {
  ...
  if (addToLinkedList(self, node->object) == NULL) {
    // Do some house-keepeing (undo prior allocations)
    return -1;
  }
```

For the higher level application, follow your design.  For now, it may be a simple enough to exit with a failure message.

```
if (addAllToLinkedList(self, ptrs)) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Linked List failure in %s %u\n", __func__, __LINE__);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Example of not exiting:

Consider a routine that read a file into a data structure with many uses of `LinkedList` and the file was somehow corrupted leading to excessive memory allocations.  Code may want to simply free everything for that file (but just for that file), and simply report to the user "invalid file/out-of-memory" - and continue running.

```
if (addAllToLinkedList(self, ptrs)) {
  free_file_to_struct_resouces(handle);
  return oops;
}
...
return success;
```

---

**Take away**

Low level routines indicate an error *somehow*.  Higher level routines can exit code if desired.

Comment: So I should just code functions that use malloc & co so that it’s always possible to check if something went wrong when these were called? Doing so should allow whoever is going to use those function in a program of his/her own to decide, on a case to case basis, whether to keep propagating the error out or to immediately kill the execution.

Comment: Specifically, if one of these function is used to build another helper/library function, the programmer should keep signaling the error in some way, while in a code which manages the actual execution of a program it **might** be sensible to just terminate on failure (or to just handle it in some way and to display an error message, the same way you did with that last example). Did I get it right?

Comment: Basically, this is a more versatile approach. I mean, malloc itself could have been made so that it would always terminate the program on failure (and I think there's even an alternative function that does so), but the fact that it doesn't gives options to the user to treat these occurences in the most appropriate way depending on the context.

Comment: @Gian Agree on all 3.  Think of code in layers.  The closer to the bottom, the less likely an `exit()` is desirable for making portable code.  If I employed a tool set/library that did all sorts of great things, but would `exit()` on rare occasions, I could see setting aside an otherwise nice package.  Yes,  handling errors in C is a chore.

Comment: This actually makes a lot of sense keeping in mind what I've recently studied (I'm still in university) about exceptions (which get thrown at a lower level and get handled at a higher level). It actually makes me appreciate those a whole lot more. Now I actually get why they are so convenient: basically they automatize this process of propagating the error upward.

Comment: @Gian Error handle is a deep subject with many POVs.  Sometimes error handling is nil, get the program shipped ASAP.   Other times it is life critical.  For me, error handling is a pragmatic yet big factor in code design - how to detect/handle efficiently can steer algorithm selection.   This is the engineering of programming: not excessive attention to errors, but enough.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the broader circumstances. For some programs, simply aborting is the right thing to do.

For some applications, the right thing to do is to shrink caches and try the `malloc` again. For some multithreaded programs, just waiting (to give other threads a chance to free memory) and retrying will work.

For applications that need to be highly reliable, you need an application level solution. One solution that I've used and battle tested is this:

1. Have an emergency pool of memory allocated at startup.
2. If `malloc` fails, free some of the emergency pool.
3. For calls that can't sanely handle a `NULL` response, sleep and retry.
4. Have a service thread that tries to refill the emergency pool.
5. Have code that uses caching respond to a non-full emergency pool by reducing memory consumption.
6. If you have the ability to shed load, for example, by shifting load to other instances, do so if the emergency pool isn't full.
7. For discretionary actions that require allocating a lot of memory, check the level of the emergency pool and don't do the action if it's not full or close to it.
8. If the emergency pool gets empty, abort.

Comment: Regarding (3), make sure that there is a limit to how many retries and sleeps are done before the code gives up, and have a policy about what happens when you do run out of retries.  Consider how long the delay is — what's acceptable?  A second might be OK in a word processor; it probably isn't in the launch controls for a SpaceX Falcon 9 rocket.

Comment: Very nice answer, albeit rather for advanced programmers.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's really hard to sanely handle memory allocation failures at literally every point in your code where memory is allocated. For the majority of cases, you can only retry forever or abort the process.

Comment: "Retry forever" worries me — YMMV.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That code will keep draining the emergency pool (per 2). Eventually, either the other mechanisms will allow the allocation to succeed or 8 will kick in. It's just not possible to identify every single place memory is allocated and sanely handle failure in that code.

Comment: Dang. You sure know how to write non-error-prone code. Maybe make a static memory pool?

Comment: This might honestly be a bit too advanced for me, but it's still really, really interesting. It seems like a brilliant and elegant approach, I'd like to try to replicate something like this just for the sake of it (as of now I don't work on anything that might require a solution this much complex). Thank you for your reply!

PS: How much memory would be sensible to reserve to the emergency pool?

Comment: @Gian Looking at my (10 years old now) code, it defaulted to 1,024 blocks each 64KB in size. Both parameters were tunable either by overriding defaults set by the application code or tuned by the admin in a configuration file. The default low water mark to trigger severe load shedding was 1/2 and the default high water mark to stop it was 3/4. The default rate to check on the status and possibly try to re-acquire lost blocks was 120ms.